# List bullets like 1) 2) 3)

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I need this types of bullets using CSS

> 1)    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
>
> 2)    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
>
> 3)    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit

Any one have a idea about this ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use CSS counters. The counter-increment CSS property is used to increase the value of CSS Counters by a given value. The counter's value can be reset using the counter-reset CSS property. Try this

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol li:before {
  content: counter(item) ")";
  padding-right: 5px;
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
</ol>
```